# gradle: java: Cannot find System Java Compiler

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle

How can I gradle my hello.java project? Right now I get the error message "Cannot find System Java Compiler". However, for me everything seems fine configured on this Ubuntu 14:

```
user:~/program/java/src/main/java$ javac hello.java 
user:~/program/java/src/main/java$ ls
hello.class  hello.java
user:~/program/java/src/main/java$ java hello 
Hello World!
user:~/program/java/src/main/java$ cd ../../../
user:~/program/java$ ls
build  build.gradle  src
user:~/program/java$ gradle build
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

* Try: ...

BUILD FAILED
```

My system configuration:

```
user:~/program/java$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_72
user:~/program/java$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
suser:~/program/java$ echo "$JAVA_HOME"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
user:~/program/java$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Jan 10 18:29 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java
```

JAVA_HOME is defined in /etc/environment (was restarted) and also in the $HOME/.bashrc.

So, I think I did the things mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715586/ubuntu-cannot-find-system-java-compiler-ensure-that-you-have-installed-a-jdk-n). The hints there are similar to most hints I found googling.

---

Due to Invisible Arrows answer I changed $JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

```
user:~/program/java$ echo "$JAVA_HOME"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

Still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Invisible Arrows hint, I did a [complete uninstallation of my java packages.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) Who, however, follows this should know, that the best voted answer there removes many packages you have to reinstall later.

After removing all java footprints I reinstalled java 7 jdk and gradle with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk gradle
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

From the properties you've pasted above, there seem to be two versions of Java installed:

1. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386` (most likely not JDK, but just JRE)
2. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`

The one pointed by `JAVA_HOME` seems to be JRE and not JDK.
Try changing that to point to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` and then run the Gradle build.

Also, verify that versions returned by `java` and `javac` are the same, which would confirm that they are pointing to the same JDK installation.

Comment: 'ls -l /usr/lib/jv/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386' gives 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Apr 18  2014 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0 openjdk-i386 -> java-7-openjdk-i386'. However, I will change that.

Comment: Hmmm, that is indeed strange. The other approach is to just remove all existing installations of Java, and re-install it with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. Might save a lot of trouble trying to troubleshoot the existing issue :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to go to Window->Preferences and in Git->Arguments, set it to 'Workspace JRE' which I already have setup in Eclipse's Java->'Installed JRE' settings, versus the default option 'Use Gradle wrapper's default'.

Comment: I don't know how do that from terminal but in Eclipse is too easy, only need to go to Gradle Task View -> build -> right click->Open Gradle Configuration -> JAVA_HOME -> and put the current value of your enviroment, something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

I hope this help you