# Building a JavaFX (JFXtras) project in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm trying to build [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) ([the official JFXtras library](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras)) with Gradle, but I keep getting this error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jfxtras-menu:compileJava'.
.......
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.
```

I'm using:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I can compile a simple HelloWorld.java program successfully.

What might I be doing wrong?

Thank you all.

---

UPDATE:

With @Evans Belloeil suggestion, I still get no success. I get an error similar to the earlier one:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jfxtras-menu:compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Have you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613693/error-while-importing-projects ?

Comment: Please check out the Update @Evans Belloeil

Comment: Make sure you don't have 2 java version installed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879358/gradle-java-cannot-find-system-java-compiler like in this thread

Comment: And if you have eclipse please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913397/when-i-am-running-gradle-project-via-eclipse-i-got-some-exception